# Flash Combo box value trailing zero removed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a combobox component in flash with a cost value. When the product is selected in the list it shows the value in a dynamic text field but removes the trailing zero's.

i.e.

```
combobox2.addItem ( {data:99.00, label: "my brilliant product"} );
```

returns '99'

I'd appreciate any help with this!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is being stored as a `Number`, and later being displayed as a `String`, you'll have to use a `NumberFormatter` on it:

```
import flash.globalization.NumberFormatter;

var formatter:NumberFormatter = new NumberFormatter("en-US");
formatter.trailingZeros = true;

dynamicTextField.text = formatter.formatNumber(combobox2.selectedItem.data);
```

**Edit:** Come to think of it, this may be overkill for what you're doing. You can just as easily use `Number.toFixed()`:

```
dynamicTextField.text = combobox2.selectedItem.data.toFixed(2);
```